# mmm dd, yyyy hh:mm AM/PM not being recognized in excel

Tags: excel

I have an Excel file in which the dates are in this format:
`mmm dd, yyyy hh:mm AM/PM` for example (Aug 19, 2021 10:15 AM)

Sadly, Excel is not recognizing it as text. I tried all listed methods but none does work. I need this field to be recognized as a `date` instead of `text`. How can this be done?

Comment: I cannot reproduce, make sure there are no extra spaces or other unprintable characters.  Also `Aug` must be a version of the month your local setting will recognize as a month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for a long time and trying various methods (trying different versions of excel, using python code to convert the sheet, using format option in excel...) I found a solution.

Changing the region settings (Start>type-Run>enter>type-control international>enter) from Match Windows display language to English (United States) worked.

After performing the change excel was able to recognize the format as date and I was able to sort.